# Backspace key highlights text instead of deleting it in Excel 2010 VBA combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform, backspace

This annoying little problem has me at my wits end. I'm building a project in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) for Excel 2010, and it involves several userforms with comboboxes populated from lists of data. For whatever reason, the backspace key has suddenly stopped functioning normally when used in these comboboxes. Have a look at this partial screenshot:

[image]

The box with the highlighting in it is a combobox populated with `"Test Item No.1"`, `"Test Item No.2"`, etc. So if I've got `"Test Item No.5"` in there, and I want to backspace the 5 and put in a 1, I can't anymore. It just highlights. I say "anymore" because this was working fine yesterday. I've tried loading a previous version of the file, and also restarting my computer. Still not working. Help please!

Comment: have you checked properties of that combobox? is it enabled? is it restricted to only certain entries?

Comment: Yes it is enabled. No it is not restricted to certain entries. Anything can go in it; it's just populated so that it gives suggestions while typing.

Comment: it sounds almost like a setting of your keyboard. does this only happen in that combobox?

Comment: It's happening in all my comboboxes which are populated. For non populated ones (Such as the Quantity box in the screenshot), the backspace key works normally.

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell it's not happening in any other application. So the problem is only in Excel, and only in coboboxes populated from lists of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the MatchEntry property. It isn't just highlighting the text, it is making the deletion then making an autosuggestion based on the characters that are already there.

Take the following as an example:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "AA"
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "AB"
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "BB"
End Sub
```

If you select "AB" then delete the "B" Excel will suggest "AA". As I'm assuming the reason for the MatchEntry property being set to Complete is that you don't want users creating invalid entries, I don't think there's a whole lot you can do.

Comment: THANK YOU! Yes, that was the problem. I still have no idea how all of my userforms got this property set this way, but they did... somehow. And actually, I don't mind users making invalid entries- that just gives them an error asks them to enter the data again.